# ng-zorro NzDrawerService nzOffsetX dynamically

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I dynamically create a component inside a drawer using the NzDrawerService. The issue is that need to set nzOffsetX  after an event is passed, which I cannot do with this API.

https://ng.ant.design/components/drawer/en#components-drawenr-demo-service

Can anyone help me? I am stuck for a long time here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the properties of NzDrawerRef.

```
openDrawer(): void {
  this.drawerRef = this.drawerService.create({
    ...
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    (this.drawerRef as any).nzOffsetX = 100;
  }, 2000)
}
```